# Nuance Dragon Speech Sdk intergration into flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-web

stackoverflow community I am a flutter developer and started an application having speech recognition system. I am using **Nuance Dragon Speech Sdk** for this purpose but it is does not have flutter support. So any one please suggest. Either I should use another Speech Recognition Sdk in flutter which is best Specifically in medical terms and words. Or build flutter app calling native sdk and how ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [speech_to_text](https://pub.dev/packages/speech_to_text) and [flutter_tts](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_tts)

Also, you can wrap your **Nuance Dragon Speech Sdk** with `MethodChannel` ([platform-channels](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-channels))

Comment: My project is for medical field so dragon sdk i use. but Problem is how to do method channel thing like android and ios in web?

Comment: it is done in android and ios but i am not understanding how to do method channel part in web folder @Eugene Kuzmenko

Comment: I can't find any info that Nuance Dragon Speech Sdk supports web. If it supports only Android, iOS, Windows, you can't use it for the web. If this sdk supports web(and you have some sdk for JS) you can look at https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/tree/master/packages/firebase_core/firebase_core_web or any other package that have web support and use additional js stuff. @zahidmahmood

Comment: It has support for web in .Net and Js. but any way was able to use it finally for web. Flutter is Full of challenges in order to develop good applications. Anyway thanks for your reply and help. @ Eugene Kuzmenko

Comment: Hi Zahid, were you able to get Dragon to work with a flutter desktop app on windows? Or what scenarios were you able to support?